# Nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:76

Tags: linux, nginx, web-server

The Nginx configuration is just like the default:

[image: image-1]

[image: image-2]

I couldn't find any clue about this error. Can anyone help me?
Any help would be grateful.
Thank You.

Comment: Please copy the text of configuration files, rather than posting screenshots.

Comment: Sorry, the number of words are limited...

Comment: Excluding the comments helps...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you already have:

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

which means your servers are included from there 
(by default symlinked from `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`)

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server

Answer (score 3):

There is a server directive outside of the http section, this needs to be nested within http rather than as a seperate section. Ideally any server apart from the default should be set-up in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/$sitename.conf`.

Comment: this answer is misleading

Comment: +1 for the explanation on the directive's context which is the important thing to remember and is missing in the accepted answer. However, note that nginx default directories have changed and it's now better to use symlinks with the new structure using sites-enabled / sites-available directories.

Comment: @ADM - I wouldn't say the answer is misleading, it is absolutely correct. It may have been 'easier' to say that the asker has one `}` in the wrong place (it is currently before the server block, and should be after) - but this answer explains what the actual issue is, rather than 'only' offering the solution

Answer (score 0):

This error is also presented if the server fails to bind the IP address and port. Like if another web server is running on the specified port, for example. Configuration file testing said everything was ok.

Looking at /var/log/nginx/error.log clearly showed the problem though.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but that doesn't sound right to me - the error itself (i.e. the question's title) does say the config test does not pass.